# Does keras support custom numpy strides?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, theano, keras

Consider a 1D numpy array. One can simulate sliding windows upon this array by changing the shape and strides of the array. For example consider the a half parabola on which we apply two sliding windows:

```
data = numpy.arange(20)
data **= 2
item_size = data.itemsize

data_input  = numpy.ndarray(
    buffer  = data.data,
    dtype   = data.dtype,
    shape   = (data.shape[0] - 4 + 1, 2),
    strides = (item_size, item_size),
    offset  = 0
)

data_output  = numpy.ndarray(
    buffer  = data.data,
    dtype   = data.dtype,
    shape   = (data.shape[0] - 4 + 1, 2),
    strides = (item_size, item_size),
    offset  = 2 * item_size
)
```

Here each row in `data_input` has a matching row in `data_output` which precede each other in `data`. That is:

```
list(zip(data_input.tolist(), data_output.tolist()))
```

The output are the row tuples of inputs and outputs, to which we'll fit a neural network shortly.

```
[([  0,   1], [  4,   9]),
 ([  1,   4], [  9,  16]),
 ([  4,   9], [ 16,  25]),
 ([  9,  16], [ 25,  36]),
 ([ 16,  25], [ 36,  49]),
 ([ 25,  36], [ 49,  64]),
 ([ 36,  49], [ 64,  81]),
 ([ 49,  64], [ 81, 100]),
 ([ 64,  81], [100, 121]),
 ([ 81, 100], [121, 144]),
 ([100, 121], [144, 169]),
 ([121, 144], [169, 196]),
 ([144, 169], [196, 225]),
 ([169, 196], [225, 256]),
 ([196, 225], [256, 289]),
 ([225, 256], [289, 324]),
 ([256, 289], [324, 361])]
```

Notice that the 2 `1`'s shown above refer to the same memory. That is, we've created a sliding window *view* instead of a *copy*. The same goes for all `4`'s, all `9`'s, etc.

I would like to know whether it is safe to use these for training a Keras neural network. For example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim=3, input_dim=2, init="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=2, input_dim=3, init="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.000001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True))

model.fit(data_input, data_output, nb_epoch=100000, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

numpy.sqrt( ((model.predict(data_input) - data_output) ** 2).mean() )
```

The code seems to work, as the weights have normal values between -2 and 2 and the resulting RMSE is around 0.65.

However, I might be pushing my luck. Does Keras consider that

1. strides may take unusual values, in particular smaller than what `numpy.zeros(...)` creates
2. different elements in the data may refer to the same memory
3. elements in inputs may refer to the same memory als elements in the output.

Please do not answer with the alternative to simply materialize all the windows separately, nor with alternative libraries.

I would like to know whether it is safe to use Keras like this, and whether the results are the same as when the data was materialized completely. If the answer depends on the backend, please answer it for both backend (Theano / Tensorflow).

Comment: 2 and 3 should not be a problem, because `keras` should not be attempting to modify the data

Comment: @Eric That would make sense, and actually I was also thinking that. I was hoping a theano / tensorflow / keras expert could confirm this, preferably someone from the respective developer communities, or Bengio's group, etc. No offence though, I sincerely appreciate your comment. But I don't like the word "should", as it suggests that you are only speculating.